# Why Configuration return wrong connection string?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get configuration string from my appsettings.Development, but returned string is wrong. (Default SqlLite name for database).

My appsettings.Development:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data source=BondarenkoStore.db"
  }
}
```

My Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(opt => 
{
    opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

Returned connection string - "Data Source=.\Data\SQlLiteDatabase.db"`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "ElmahIo": {
      "ApiKey": "API_KEY",
      "LogId": "LOG_ID"
    },
    "Serilog": {
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "File",
          "Args": {
            "rollingInterval": "Day",
            "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AppSettings": {
    "BaseUrlWeb": "https://localhost:7063/"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "HrSoultion": "server=.;database=Maqta;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }
}
```

put it in the appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

**"DefaultConnection"** always will return default connection string. Any other option will help.